# Problem in configuring Hudson

Tags: java, hudson

I want to create a server(Windows) from which I want to handle some build operation on different OS machines like windows, mac, linux;
I got that Hudson Master/Slave configuration can solve my problem. I searched a lot but didn't find any suitable and complete link to do this.

I deployed Hudson war on Tomcat and able to create job which takes a batch command and build a java app on same machine.

But if I want to do any build on different machine how I can do this.
I have some doubts like:-

1: for different machine I have to do Hudson setup again like deployment in tomcat ??

2: How to setup a slave on Other machine.

3: Why I am not getting option like "tied on a project" for created Job.

I think answer to these questions can give me some strength to look ahead.
Expecting a favorable reply

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All the information about setting up a Master / Slave system on different environments is documented at -

- http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds
- http://wiki.hudsonci.org/display/HUDSON/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines